# How to mock method which accepts out parameter

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I'm using `moq` and would like to mock a method which accepts `out` parameter:

```
protected void GetDataRow(string id, out DataRow dataRow)
```

This is what I tried:

```
dataMock.Protected().Setup("GetDataRow", ItExpr.IsAny<string>(), ItExpr.IsAny<DataRow>());
```

However, it returns:

```
System.ArgumentException : Member DataManager.GetDataRow does not exist.
```

If I change the dataRow parameter not to be `out`, everything works as expected.

How should I create a mock in this case?

Comment: Don't the docs help? https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: This should be added to Moq Documentation here in SO

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `IsAny<DataRow>` with `out` parameter. Instead of the `IsAny<DataRow>` you can create local `DataRow` variable and pass that one to the mock. The call of the mock later on will return `dataRow` as is, so you can use that one to verify your test expectations.

```
DataRow dataRow = new DataRow();
dataMock.Protected().Setup("GetDataRow", ItExpr.IsAny<string>(), out dataRow);
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not seem to work, I'm getting: 
error CS1615: Argument 3 may not be passed with the 'out' keyword

Answer (score 1):

It can be done since moq 4.8.0-rc1 (2017-12-08). You can use `ItExpr.Ref<DataRow>.IsAny` for match any value for `ref` or `out` parameters. In your case:

```
dataMock.Protected().Setup("GetDataRow", ItExpr.IsAny<string>(), ItExpr.Ref<DataRow>.IsAny);
```